# SSRS Using Report Parameters in the FileName for data driven subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using this query in a data driven subscription to run a number of reports.  This query works and provides the reports with the appropriate file name.  My issue is that I am hard coding the fiscal year and accounting period in the file name.  The actual report that this subscription runs has a parameter for fiscal year (FY) and accounting period (AP).  Is there a way to use those parameter values in this query for the filename instead of hardcoding them>?  Thanks for the help......

```
    select 
s.operating_unit
,s.region_cd

,case when extract (year from current_date)  > 8 then 
    extract (year from current_date)  +1
    else
    extract (year from current_date)  
    end as TempYear

,case when extract (month from current_date)  >8 then 
    extract (month from current_date)  - 8
    else
    extract (month from current_date) + 4 
    end as TempDay

,trim(TempYear (FORMAT '9(4)')) as vFY
,trim(TempDay (FORMAT '9(2)')) as vAP

, 'FA Additions – '|| trim(s.operating_unit) || ' - ' || s.region_cd || ‘ –‘ || vFY || ’-‘ || vAP as FileName
, 'http://reportweb/admin/rfs/Report Library/Fixed Asset Backup/FA Additions'  as FilePath


from psfs.ps_asset p
inner join rfs.stn_ops_hierarchies s on s.operating_unit = p.business_unit
where p.business_unit between 'A0460 ' and 'A0466'

group by s.operating_unit, s.region_cd
order by s.operating_unit, s.region_cd
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need your query to use similar tables so that it could get the year and accounting period in your data-driven subscription query.

Assuming that the tables from your query does have the fields necessary:

```
SELECT
s.operating_unit
,s.region_cd
, 'FA Additions – '|| trim(s.operating_unit) || ' - ' || s.region_cd || ' -  ' + YEAR(DateField) + '-' + PeriodField as FileName
, 'http://reportweb/admin/rfs/Report Library/Fixed Asset Backup/FA Additions'  as FilePath 
FROM psfs.ps_asset p
INNER JOIN rfs.stn_ops_hierarchies s on s.operating_unit = p.business_unit
WHERE p.business_unit between 'A0400' and 'A0899'

group by s.operating_unit, s.region_cd
order by s.operating_unit, s.region_cd
```

You may need to add your parameters to the Data-Driven query using the same logic you use for the default values so you only get the needed year/period.

Comment: .......Thanks for the feedback.  I figured that out after I posted this question.

Comment: .........Please see the revised code in my original post.  This works in Teradata but when I move it to the query in a Data Driven Subscription, it cannot create the query.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks for your help